# Why does bm fail for DeclareMathOperator

Tags: bold, bm

I like the bm package. However, it seems to me the line

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{\bm{curl}}
```

won't make curl bold. Although changing bm to mathbf will do the job, I have to use mathbf everytime afterwards to keep consistency, which is something I'd like to avoid.
Are there any solutions to that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 12):

The definitions are the wrong way round.

You want something like

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\curlinternal}{curl}
\bmdefine\curl{\bm{\curlinternal}}
```

Or you could save TeX some work figuring out what that means and do

```
\newcommand\curl{\mathop{\mathbf{curl}}}
```

instead.

PS *of course* you like the `bm` package:-)

Comment: Isn't it `\mathop{{}\mathbf{curl}}`?

Comment: @yo' my eyes are not as good as they once were, but I reckon there is more than 1 letter in `curl`

Comment: Ah, I always miss something with `\mathop`, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: best customer service ever:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- this construction isn't blindingly obvious.  in fact, reading the output of `texdoc bm` it still is neither blindingly obvious, nor even hinted at.  why don't you do a good deed and add it.  please?